# Are JS object property names given a default key(name) value when initialised?

Tags: javascript, eloquent

In this problem I understand most of what is going on: 
The function countBy takes any group of iterable items(list,object,array) and then sorts them by a given groupName--which console.log'd below is a function that names the items either true or false based on whether or not it is true they are greater than 2.. However, **what I dont understand and seek to, is how when the name property is initially pushed to each object in the array below their value is inherited?** I see that a name property is pushed but dont see the groupName implicitly defined. Do you? Is it some sort of default behavior of object properties?

```
  function countBy(items, groupName) {
  let counts = [];
  for (let item of items) {
    let name = groupName(item);
    let known = counts.findIndex(c => c.name == name);
    if (known == -1) {
      counts.push({name, count: 1});
    } else {
      counts[known].count++;
    }
  }
  return counts;
}

console.log(countBy([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], n => n > 2));
 // → [{name: false, count: 2}, {name: true, count: 3}]
```

Comment: I feel like it should be `counts.push({name: name, count: 1})` - is that what puzzles you?

Comment: It's an ES6 shorthand object literal syntax. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Syntax

Comment: Thank you @Phil That's the documentation I was looking for!